# C# How to return null or an model

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, poco, c#-7.0

I have Store Model that I want to return null if my model is null.

```
public Store Details() => db.Store.Single(s => s.Id == 1);
```

This query sometimes return a value and sometimes returns null. How can I specific the return type to include both?

Comment: A class reference is by default nullable, so could you please add a little more description in what you want to achieve? If you want to know how to use linq to return null u could use SelectFirstOrDefault

Comment: Check extension methods defined in `Enumerable`, together with `Single()` you will find, for example, `SingleOrDefault()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to use

```
public Store Details() => db.Store.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == 1);
```

Comment: You can try `SingleOrDefault()` too; instead `FirstOrDefault()`.

Answer (score 2):

Use **SingleOrDefault** instead of FirstOrDefault, because exception is thrown if more than one is found

```
// throws an exception if there's more than one entity that fits the filter part. 
public Store Details() => db.Store.SingleOrDefault(s => s.Id == 1);

// doesn't throw if there's more than one entity that fits the filter part
public Store Details() => db.Store.FirstOrDefault(s => s.Id == 1);
```